# Can't execute easy fatalities in Mortal Mombat X

Tags: mortal-kombat-x

I can't do easy fatalities, like *(Hold RT + X/A)*.

Other than that, the other fatalities with usual inputs are not a problem, but easy ones don't work at all. Also, I do have 2 of those easy fatality tokens.

Why aren't they working? Am I doing something wrong? I am pretty darn sure my controller is functioning properly.

Comment: Whoever up voted this , I thank you. May we cross paths someday. :')